# Tests using cypress open pass and tests using cypress run --browser chrome fail

Tags: cypress

Seemingly out of nowhere (I'm still investigating) my tests using `cypress open` will pass without issue and testing using `cypress run --browser chrome` will fail.

I have checkout a commit from the past when I know I was able to run tests using `cypress run --browser chrome` and they passed, but they are still failing.

```
AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: `[data-test=tableRow]`, but never found it.
```

Is there a reason why tests being run `cypress run --browser chrome` would not be able to find components, but `cypress open` would?

Comment: As in most cases it happens due to some kind of delay in element identification, Try adding additional explicit wait using `cy.wait(xxxx)` before your action, it might help

Comment: It would help if you share the failing test.